# How to convert a PSQL query which has subqueries to a valid KnexJS

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

In my DB I'm running a PSQL query to get data as result from 2 tables.
The query works well but I have now to translated in Knex but I got stuck as I have a sub-query as you see and don't know the best way of doing it.

An example of what I was trying

```
builder
 .whereIn(
      columns.id,
      builder
        .where(feedColumns.conversationId, columns.id)
        .groupBy(columns.id)
          )
```

But that fails and do not even console log the query as I'm using in the end `toString()` to see what is generated :(

The query in PSQL which works

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "conversation"
WHERE
    "conversation"."id" IN(
        SELECT
            "feed"."conversation_id" FROM "feed"
        WHERE
            "feed"."status" = 'PENDING_ANSWER')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
knex('conversation').whereIn('id', 
  knex('feed')
    .select('feed.conversation_id')
    .where('feed.status', 'PENDING_ANSWER')
)
```